# Why RMS value used in transformer equivalent model?

Tags: transformer, rms

The equivalent model of a real transformer is given:
[image]

Why do we use RMS values of input and output voltage when analyzing the model? The main confusion comes from the fact that real transformers only work on basis of changing flux ( or changing voltage ), then why would we want to consider the equivalent DC value of AC ( which is RMS value ) ?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to describe an AC waveform. We can use the rms (the heating power), the peak, the peak-to-peak, the average of DC. Each representation will have its own advantages and disadvantages, and situations where it's more appropriate. If we know the waveshape (and if that's not specified it's usually sinusoidal), then it's trivial to convert between any pair of numbers.

Customarily, meters are calibrated to read the rms value of a sinusoidal waveform. If the measurement type is not specified, then it's usually rms.

If you are analysing a transformer on the basis of output as a function of input, it really doesn't matter whether input and output are measured in rms, peak, or any other consistent way, the ratio will be the same.

If you're analysing a transformer relating flux to input voltage, then it's true that measuring flux as peak is more useful. However, as flux is the integral of voltage, we need to know the entire waveform of the input voltage, not just a single number like peak. For instance a transformer with square wave drive will have a different peak_volts to peak_flux relationship than one with sine wave drive. Whatever number we use for input voltage, rms, peak or anything else, will need to be interpretted through the waveshape and Faraday's Law to arrive at the flux.

Comment: I understand that the rms values only affect the peak value and not the waveform itself and all the results will just be scaled by a constant.  Correct me if I'm wrong : So using RMS doesn't mean that I am assuming a different input source as all the components in a transformer have been approximated as linear, passive elements ?

Comment: If you assume a consistent waveshape, say sinusoidal, then rms/peak is a fixed ratio. For a square wave, rms/peak will have a different ratio (1.0 !). How you specify the amplitude of a voltage does not assume anything about the source of the voltage.